Selecting Potentiometer
I am trying to select a potentiometer that can be moved from 50 to 60K. It will be used to vary watchdog timer (39.2k resistor in the image). I wanted to use a small potentiometer, but the one I bought only moves from 52K to 54K. How do you know the minimum value and maximum value of a potentiometer from Digikey (or similar site)?


Drona - Hi, Please [edit] the question and: (a) Add a schematic showing the circuit you used to measure a potentiometer you bought "only moves from 52K to 54K". (If you don't already know, while editing, press Ctrl+G (or click the "picture of mountains" icon) to start the image upload dialog.) (b) Explain why you want a potentiometer which "can be moved from 50 to 60K". Why those values? Ideally include a schematic showing the circuit which is using that pot. TY

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is stopping you from putting a 50k resistor in series with a 10k potentiometer?

Are you looking for a variable resistor rather than a potentiometer? Show us the circuit where you will use it.

Updated with circuit board image.

@Drona This is not a PCB image, this is a schematic. Not even a complete one by the look of it. Which resistor shown here is the potentiometer?

39.2k resistor in the image.

A potentiometer will have several characteristics related to it's value.

The rated  or end-to-end resistance, which is the value you'll see the resistor listed and marked as.
The end resistance, which is the value from the wiper to one end when the wiper is adjusted all the way to that end.
The taper, which determines how the resistance changes from one end to the other.

If you just want a two terminal variable resistance, that's called a rheostat. You can use a potentiometer as a rheostat by connecting the wiper to one of the ends.
If you're looking on a site such as DigiKey you'll see potentiometers listed by there end-to-end resistance, for instance you might see them as 10k, 100k, 250 Ohms, etc. This will be about the maximum resistance you will get from the wiper to either end.
Looking at the datasheets you will often find the end resistance listed, this will usually be something like '2 % or 2 ohms (whichever is greater)'. When the pot is adjusted all the way to one end there will still be a small amount of resistance because of the way the connections are made to the resistive element. This will be the minimum resistance you can get from the wiper to either end.
The taper is how the resistance changes from one end to the other, for a linear taper the resistive material is evenly distributed so if you put the wiper in the middle of a 50k pot there will be 25k from the wiper to each end. A logarithmic taper will have the resistance change in a roughly logarithmic ratio, so setting it halfway will give you more resistance on one side than the other. These are used for  things like audio volume controls because the human ear has a logarithmic response so you want to vary the volume to match that.
So let's say you buy a 50k pot linear taper pot and the end resistance is rated at 1%. That means you'll have a minimum resistance from the wiper to one end of about 500 ohms and a maximum near 50k.
If you want a range of something like 50k to 60k you need to start with the minimum value and use a fixed resistor for that, then use a pot that will make up the difference, so a 50k resistor in series with a 10k pot.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you want it to be more precise you would need to compensate for end resistance and tolerances, that gets a bit more complicated, you would need to use a slightly lower value fixed resistor and small trimmer pot to set the minimum, and use a slightly higher value pot with a fixed resistor in series with a trimmer to set the maximum value, something like this:

simulate this circuit
